# Reading LM35 temperature sensor through long wire

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read temperature through long wire, using raspberry pi.

I use [mcp3008](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) that I power using one of my rpi 5V pins. 
I use the same 5V pin to operate my [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) temperature sensor.
The `Vout` of my lm35 goes into channel 0 of the mcp3008, and I use some method to read the values (irrelevant to the story)
The sensor `Vout= 10mV/C`, i.e `0.215V= 21.5 celcius`

When I attach the sensor directly to my circuit, and try to read the values, I see the values are correct.
When I later use a twisted copper pair (telephone line), over around 5-10meters, my circuit wouldn't measure it correctly.
The readings are very inaccurate, goes around between 15-30 degrees, every second something else. 
If I use a multimeter, I see the voltage is very steady, around what I sampled before (0.215V)
I have two questions in this matter:

1. How does the mcp3008 samples the input channel? because the voltage is OK
2. What simple measures I can take in order to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large variations suggest that your sensor is oscillating. The wire presents a capacitive load to the output, that can me make it go unstable.

Put a resistor of 2k in series with the output of the LM35 as suggested in the datasheet.

Check the section "Capacitive Drive Capability" for more information.

Comment: Agreed. See [page 8](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf).

Comment: @Mario Thanks. I didn't realize that wiring adds capacitance. I know it has resistance but I forgot that one. So I'll use a 2k resistor between my Vout to CH0 input. But what would be my new equation to measure the temp? I couldn't calculate the current there, so how am I suppose to calculate the voltage drop on the resistor?

Comment: The input of the ADC (in this case) is again a capacitor. It has a value of 20pF. There is also a sampling switch at the input that adds some resistance. You have to consider the R*C time constant and the frequency of the ADC to determine the maximum allowed resistance. I think the error will be small to negligible. If the 2k resistors works, try a smaller one and see if that still works.

Comment: @Mario I used 2KOhm resistor in between `Vout` to `ch0` and unfortunately readings still variates alot. I see that it is also suggested in the spreadsheet to use a 0.1mF capacitor in parallel, between `ch0` and `GND`,  but I'm not sure if it will work? The whole point is to increase the capacitance between the two parts, right? How is a capacitor between ch0 to ground increases the capacitance? Also,  I'm not sure I understand your point regarding RC time and determining the maximum allowed resistance